# Kafka Connect S3 Connector OutOfMemory errors with TimeBasedPartitioner

Tags: amazon-s3, out-of-memory, apache-kafka-connect

I'm currently working with the [Kafka Connect S3 Sink Connector 3.3.1](https://docs.confluent.io/3.3.1/connect/connect-storage-cloud/kafka-connect-s3/docs/configuration_options.html) to copy Kafka messages over to S3 and I have OutOfMemory errors when processing late data.

I know it looks like a long question, but I tried my best to make it clear and simple to understand.
I highly appreciate your help.

#### High level info

- The connector does a simple byte to byte copy of the Kafka messages and add the length of the message at the beginning of the byte array (for decompression purposes).

  - This is the role of the `CustomByteArrayFormat` class (see configs below)
- The data is partitioned and bucketed according to the `Record` timestamp

  - The `CustomTimeBasedPartitioner` extends the `io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner` and its sole purpose is to override the `generatePartitionedPath` method to put the topic at the end of the path.
- The total heap size of the Kafka Connect process is of 24GB (only one node)
- The connector process between 8,000 and 10,000 messages per second
- Each message has a size close to 1 KB
- The Kafka topic has 32 partitions

#### Context of OutOfMemory errors

- Those errors only happen when the connector has been down for several hours and has to catch up data
- When turning the connector back on, it begins to catch up but fail very quickly with OutOfMemory errors

#### Possible but incomplete explanation

- The `timestamp.extractor` configuration of the connector is set to `Record` when those OOM errors happen
- Switching this configuration to `Wallclock` (i.e. the time of the Kafka Connect process) DO NOT throw OOM errors and all of the late data can be processed, but the late data is no longer correctly bucketed

  - All of the late data will be bucketed in the `YYYY/MM/dd/HH/mm/topic-name` of the time at which the connector was turn back on
- So my guess is that while the connector is trying to correctly bucket the data according to the `Record` timestamp, it does too many parallel reading leading to OOM errors

  - The `"partition.duration.ms": "600000"` parameter make the connector bucket data in six 10 minutes paths per hour (`2018/06/20/12/[00|10|20|30|40|50]` for 2018-06-20 at 12pm)
  - Thus, with 24h of late data, the connector would have to output data in `24h * 6 = 144` different S3 paths.
  - Each 10 minutes folder contains 10,000 messages/sec * 600 seconds = 6,000,000 messages for a size of 6 GB
  - If it does indeed read in parallel, that would make 864GB of data going into memory
- I think that I have to correctly configure a given set of parameters in order to avoid those OOM errors but I don't feel like I see the big picture

  - The `"flush.size": "100000"` imply that if there is more dans 100,000 messages read, they should be committed to files (and thus free memory)

    - With messages of 1KB, this means committing every 100MB
    - But even if there is 144 parallel readings, that would still only give a total of 14.4 GB, which is less than the 24GB of heap size available
    - Is the `"flush.size"` the number of record to read **per partition** before committing? Or maybe **per connector's task**?
  - The way I understand `"rotate.schedule.interval.ms": "600000"` config is that data is going to be committed every 10 minutes even when the 100,000 messages of `flush.size` haven't been reached.

**My main question would be what are the maths allowing me to plan for memory usage given:**

- the number or records per second
- the size of the records
- the number of Kafka partitions of the topics I read from
- the number of Connector tasks (if this is relevant)
- the number of buckets written to per hour (here 6 because of the `"partition.duration.ms": "600000"` config)
- the maximum number of hours of late data to process

#### Configurations

S3 Sink Connector configurations

```
{
  "name": "xxxxxxx",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
    "s3.region": "us-east-1",
    "partition.duration.ms": "600000",
    "topics.dir": "xxxxx",
    "flush.size": "100000",
    "schema.compatibility": "NONE",
    "topics": "xxxxxx,xxxxxx",
    "tasks.max": "16",
    "s3.part.size": "52428800",
    "timezone": "UTC",
    "locale": "en",
    "format.class": "xxx.xxxx.xxx.CustomByteArrayFormat",
    "partitioner.class": "xxx.xxxx.xxx.CustomTimeBasedPartitioner",
    "schema.generator.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.schema.DefaultSchemaGenerator",
    "name": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
    "s3.bucket.name": "xxxxxxx",
    "rotate.schedule.interval.ms": "600000",
    "path.format": "YYYY/MM/dd/HH/mm",
    "timestamp.extractor": "Record"
}
```

Worker configurations

```
bootstrap.servers=XXXXXX
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
consumer.auto.offset.reset=earliest
consumer.max.partition.fetch.bytes=2097152
consumer.partition.assignment.strategy=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor
group.id=xxxxxxx
config.storage.topic=connect-configs
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
status.storage.topic=connect-status
rest.advertised.host.name=XXXX
```

**Edit**:

I forgot to add an example of the errors I have:

```
2018-06-21 14:54:48,644] ERROR Task XXXXXXXXXXXXX-15 threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:482)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[2018-06-21 14:54:48,645] ERROR Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:483)
[2018-06-21 14:54:48,645] ERROR Task XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-15 threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:148)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:484)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:265)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:182)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:150)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:190)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I was finally able to understand how the Heap Size usage works in the Kafka Connect S3 Connector

- The S3 Connector will write the data of each Kafka partition into partitioned *`paths`*

  - The way those *`paths`* are partitioned depends on the `partitioner.class` parameter;
  - By default, it is by timestamp, and the value of `partition.duration.ms` will then determine the duration of each partitioned *`paths`*.
- The S3 Connector will allocate a buffer of `s3.part.size` Bytes per Kafka partition (for all topics read) and per partitioned *`paths`*

  - Example with 20 partitions read, a `timestamp.extractor` set to `Record`, `partition.duration.ms` set to 1h, `s3.part.size` set to 50 MB

    - The Heap Size needed each hour is then equal to `20 * 50 MB` = 1 GB;
    - But, `timestamp.extractor` being set to `Record`, messages having a timestamp corresponding to an earlier hour then the one at which they are read will be buffered in this earlier hour buffer. Therefore, in reality, the connector will need minimum `20 * 50 MB * 2h` = 2 GB of memory because there is always late events, and more if there is events with a lateness superior to 1 hour;
    - Note that this isn't true if `timestamp.extractor` is set to `Wallclock` because there will virtually never be late events as far as Kafka Connect is concerned.
  - Those buffers are flushed (i.e. leave the memory) at 3 conditions

    - `rotate.schedule.interval.ms` time has passed

      - This flush condition is **always** triggered.
    - `rotate.interval.ms` time has passed **in terms of `timestamp.extractor` time**

      - This means that if `timestamp.extractor` is set to `Record`, 10 minutes of `Record` time can pass in less or more and 10 minutes of *actual time*

        - For instance, when processing late data, 10 minutes worth of data will be processed in a few seconds, and if `rotate.interval.ms` is set to 10 minutes then this condition will trigger every second (as it should);
        - On the contrary, if there is a pause in the flow of events, this condition will not trigger until it sees an events with a timestamp showing that more than `rotate.interval.ms` has passed since the condition last triggered.
    - `flush.size` messages have been read in less than `min(rotate.schedule.interval.ms`, `rotate.interval.ms)`

      - As for the `rotate.interval.ms`, this condition might never trigger if there is not enough messages.
  - Thus, you need to plan for `Kafka partitions * s3.part.size` Heap Size at the very least

    - If you are using a `Record` timestamp for partitioning, you should multiply it by `max lateness in milliseconds / partition.duration.ms`

      - This is a worst case scenario where you have constantly late events in all partitions and for the all range of `max lateness in milliseconds`.
- The S3 connector will also buffer `consumer.max.partition.fetch.bytes` bytes per partition when it reads from Kafka

  - This is set to 2.1 MB by default.
- Finally, you should not consider that all of the Heap Size is available to buffer Kafka messages because there is also a lot of different objects in it

  - A safe consideration would be to make sure that the buffering of Kafka messages does not go over 50% of the total available Heap Size.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer. The Internet would be a better place with more people like you.

Comment: Thx Guido, appreciate it. I'm glad it's been useful.

Comment: @raphael If your connector is sinking multiple topics would you also multiple the calculation by the number of topics?

Comment: @moku Not multiple by topic but by the total number of partition all topics included.
Say you have one topic with 10 partitions and another one with 24, you'd multiply by 34.

Answer (score 1):

@raphael has explained the working perfectly. 
Pasting a small variation of similar problem (too little events to process but across many hours/days) that I had faced.

In my case I had about 150 connectors and 8 of them were failing with OOM as they had to process about 7 days worth of data (Our kafka in test env was down for about 2 weeks)

**Steps Followed:**

1. Reduced `s3.part.size` from 25MB to 5MB for all connectors. (In our scenario, `rotate.interval` was set to 10min with `flush.size` as 10000. Most of our events should easily fit with in this limit).
2. After this setting, **only one connector was still getting OOM** and this one connector goes into **OOM within 5seconds** of start (based on heap analysis), it shoots up from 200MB-1.5GB of Heap utilization. On looking at kafka offset lag, there were only **8K events** to process across all **7 days**. So this wasn't because of too many events to handle but rather **too little events to handle**/flush.
3. Since we were using Hourly partition and for an hour there were hardly 100 events, all the buffers for these 7 days were getting created without being flushed (without being released to JVM) - `7 * 24 * 5MB * 3 partitions = 2.5GB` (xmx-1.5GB)

Fix:
Perform one of the below steps until your connector catches up and then restore your old config back. (**Recommend approach - 1**)

1. Update the Connector config to process 100 or 1000 records `flush.size` (depending on how your data is structured). 
    **Drawback :** Too many small files get created in the hour, if actual events are more than 1000.
2. Change Partition to Daily so there will only be daily partitions.  
    **Drawback :** You'll now have a mix of Hourly and Daily partition in your S3.